# Hide StatusBar in Trusted Web Activities

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen, trusted-web-activity

After following the [Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa#remove_the_url_bar) about twa's and hiding the url bar I have now a working twa without url bar. But the StatusBar is still visible.

Is it possible to hide the StatusBar in twa's to get a fullscreen view?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/battlechoc_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Battlechoc.Fullscreen.Theme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <meta-data
        android:name="asset_statements"
        android:value="@string/asset_statements" />

    <activity
        android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Battlechoc.Fullscreen.Theme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
            android:value="https://battlechoc.com" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="@string/hostname"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Battlechoc.Fullscreen.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to hide status bar in certain activity ? Is it right? That is help me to understand your problem.

Comment: @BlackBlind I want to hide the status bar in the entire app if this is possible when using twa's

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide your status bar

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

hope fully it will work for you.

**UPDATE**
Ok now try this. It will enable full screen mode so it will fit on your requirements that is hide status bar.

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

// Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for my twa. The statusbar and the navigation is still visible

Comment: Where does this Java code go? I'm completely new to Android development, so a bit of help would be appreciated 

Comment: Do you want to hide status bar and navigation Bar??

Comment: @BlackBlind even your update does not work but it has to do with twa in general. [This is the corresponding open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=965329&q=component%3AUI%3EBrowser%3EMobile%3ETrustedWebActivities%20immersive&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) .. So it seems that we simply need to wait, star the issue, help with comments or even pull requests. I will track it and update this thread if anything new is going to happen